# MYSQL 'SELECT...FOR UPDATE' lock tables not work

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I put you in a situation before explaining the problem.

I have two servers, one with my website and the other with the database in MySQL.

The web connects to MySQL and uses its data to run.

Each user who opens the web for the first time is assigned a unique ID, but there are many times that these IDs are duplicated and the same ID is assigned to different users.

I obtain these IDs through the VB.net code of the web of a MySQL table called 'my_block_ids' which has the following fields: 'id', 'year' and 'type'.

The code I use to obtain the ID to be assigned to the user and lock the table until it is modified with the following ID to be assigned is the following:

```
Dim id As Integer = 0

Dim sSQL As String = "START TRANSACTION;"

sSQL &= "SELECT id FROM my_block_ids WHERE year = 2019 AND type=3 FOR UPDATE;"

id = DB.Value(sSQL)

sSQL = "UPDATE my_block_ids Set id=id+1 WHERE year = 2019 And type=3 And id=" & id.ToString & "; COMMIT;"
```

The problem I detect is that MySQL detects that all requests come from the same application/program and does not block the table with the statement 'SELECT... FOR UPDATE' assigning the same ID many times to different users.

I would be very grateful if someone can give me a solution to the problem.

Comment: So what is currently happening? Share some sample data too with desired output needed.

Comment: I have tested it's working fine for me.

Comment: MySQL would treat the queries as being from the same application if the application does not open a new connection for each user. I don't know how your application is designed, but that could e.g. be the case if you share your connection object (not the connection settings) across different threads. Could you verify that this is the case? Then you probably can use a critical section (e.g. lock your application threads). Another likely suspects is: this could be a MyISAM table (which doesn't support transactions), run `show create table my_block_ids` and check for `engine=...`  in the output.

Comment: Hello James, Do you have installed MySQL and your website in diferent servers?? What is your MySQL configuration?? 
What have you done to test it?Thanks

Comment: Hello Solarflare, I have an class named shoppingCart.vb, in that class I have a function called 'ObtainId' where I have the code specified in the post, and In that class I have a function called 'ObtainId' where I have the code specified in the post, and outside of that function I have declared the object 'DB' thus 'Private _DB As New DBManager'. The table is 'InnoDB'. Thanks!!

Comment: "I obtain these IDs through the VB.net code" Why not let the database assign the ID's with an auto increment field? Another solution would be to use a GUID in vb code.

Comment: Hello Mary, I don't use an autoincremental because the table lock doesn't work, so I still have the same problem. How would you do using GUID? Because the identifiers I need to assign to each new user must be consecutive. Thanks!!